# How to apply Django cache control on included urls?

Tags: django, pinax, django-cache

I have enabled [site-wide Django caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-site-cache), but the third-party apps I am using have not specified any cache-control expectations. So, I am guessing that their views will get cached.

The problem is that I do not want Django to cache the views of some apps. How do I apply url-level cache control on `include()`?

```
url(r"^account/", include("pinax.apps.account.urls")) #How to apply cache control here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The per-site cache is achieved through middlewares which considers only request and response instead of specific view.

However, you could achieve this by providing a patched django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware.

```
class ManagedFetchFromCacheMiddle(FetchFromCacheMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if should_exempt(request):
            request._cache_update_cache = False
            return
        return super(ManagedFetchFromCacheMiddle, self).process_request(request)

def should_exempt(request):
    """Any predicator to exempt cache on a request
    For your case, it looks like

    if request.path.startswith('/account/'):
        return True
    """
```

Replace 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware' with the path of the above in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Maybe generic version of above is suitable for commiting patch to Django community =p

Comment: Hmm. So you mean that I will then have to disable this and use per-view one.

Comment: @AppleGrew just provided a solution

Comment: I guess I will go with per view and per-template cache, since as it turns out, most of my site is dynamic. Accepted your answer in the hope this will help others. One more thing I was wondering maybe it is possible to write a function which can wrap the intended cache function around each included url. This might work, but then we need to check first what exactly `include()` returns.

Comment: @AppleGrew OK. include is used for grouped urlpatterns in Django URL dispatching and separated from cache layer IMHO